# SQL - Split values into different columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that looks like this

```
CAN | Contact | Email | Order Ref
22  | C1      |blah@b | 23334
22  | C2      |blah@b | 23334
22  | C3      |blah@b | 23334
```

How could I get this to split the contact Ids across 3 columns so there is only 1 row per CAN? Something like

```
CAN | Contact1 | Contact 2 | Contact 3|  Email | Order Ref
22  | C1       |    C2     |    C3    |blah@b | 23334
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You need google for `PIVOT` for your RDBMS

Comment: Don't do it. You have correct database model, and want to go to worse one.

Comment: @panther He doesnt want change the model, probably format the data for display.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of Contacts per CAN?

Comment: do you just want a query to display results like that?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: Ah, okay.

Comment: Maximum contacts is 3 per CAN. Yes this is just for a report.. I won't be changing the actual tables.

Comment: You need to normalize your table.

Answer (score 2):

Dont know why scimon delete his answer, but here is the final version:

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/NWB67997)**

```
with cte as(
select
    *
    ,row_number() over (partition by CAN order by Contact) as RN
from
    Table1)    
select
    CAN
    , MAX(case when RN = 1 then Contact end) as Contact1
    , MAX(case when RN = 2 then Contact end) as Contact2
    , MAX(case when RN = 3 then Contact end) as Contact3
    ,Email
    ,[Order Ref]
from
    cte
GROUP BY CAN, Email, [Order Ref]
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Nice answer.  Check out this slight alteration.  What happens if there are multiple Email or [Order Ref] values per CAN?  This version might be better or worse, depending on the desired behavior... 
http://rextester.com/CRLCI44307

Comment: @sql_knievel You shouldnt try solve hypothetical or you wont never finish your answer. For example I find weird each contact has same email. A more appropriate solution would be one with `Email1, Email2, Email3` but that wasn't what OP ask.

Comment: If you have Contact C4, this will not be shown in the result of the query because this answer not a dinamic query. But if you do not need a fourth data, then this query will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of dynamic `PIVOT` operator:

```
create table #tbl(
    can int
    ,contact varchar(3)
    ,email varchar(10)
    ,orderRef int
)

insert into #tbl values (22, 'C1', 'blah@b', 23334)
insert into #tbl values (22, 'C2', 'blah@b', 23334)
insert into #tbl values (22, 'C3', 'blah@b', 23334)


declare @columnName as varchar(max)
declare @columnNameWAlias as varchar(max)
declare @sql as nvarchar(max)


SELECT @ColumnName = 
    ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(contact)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT can, contact, email, orderRef FROM #tbl) AS Contacts

SELECT @columnNameWAlias = 
    ISNULL(@columnNameWAlias + ',','') + QUOTENAME(contact) + ' AS [Contact' + CAST(seq as varchar) + ']'
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT can, contact, email, orderRef, seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by contact) FROM #tbl) AS Contacts


SET @sql = N'
    SELECT 
    CAN
    ,' + @columnNameWAlias + 
    ',Email
    ,orderREf
FROM (
    SELECT
        can
        ,contact
        ,Email
        ,orderRef
    FROM #tbl
) tbl
PIVOT (
    MAX(contact) FOR contact IN (' + @columnName + ')
) pvt
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

drop table #tbl
```

[Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) you can find more info and examples about it.

Comment: The contact values would need to be dynamic as they won't always be C1 C2 or C3

Comment: `[C1], [C2], [C3]` can be anything. You need dynamic query to get the header

Comment: @jd0963 i have updated my answer with a dynamic `PIVOT`